# WPF DataTrigger for TextBlock to control Text

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have TextBlock

```
<TextBlock>                  
    <Run Text="{Binding Path=Value1}" />
    <Run Text="-" />
    <Run Text="{Binding Path=Value2}" />
</TextBlock>
```

I need to add such trigger: If Value2 = XXX, TextBlock should display only Value1.
Is that possible to do without converters and ViewModel modifications?

Comment: why not doing this control in your Viewmodel property  ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you don't format each `Run` individually (i.e. `FontSize`, `Foreground`) instead you can use `MultiBinding` with `StringFormat` and change `Text` binding when `Value2=XXX`

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Text">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - {1}">
                        <Binding Path="Value1"/>
                        <Binding Path="Value2"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value2}" Value="XXX">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Value1}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <TextBlock>                  
        <Run Text="{Binding Path=prop1}" />
        <Run Text="-" />
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Style>
                 <Style>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=prop2}" Value="XXX">
                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
            <Run Text="{Binding Path=prop2}" />
         </TextBlock>
    </TextBlock>
```

is the only way i found. A run has no visibility property.